# Is there a c++ trait to find the most restricted type between two types in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

I would like a type trait `common`

so that

```
common<int,int>::type              -> int
common<const int, int>::type       -> const int
common<int, int &>::type           -> int
common<int &, int &>::type         -> int &
common<int &, int const &>::type   -> int const &
```

that is the result type should be the more restricted of the two. Is there a trait in the C++11 std that can do this or do I have to roll my own?

My use case is that I have a something similar to

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct Foo {

   BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
    std::is_same
    < typename std::decay<T0>::type
    , typename std::decay<T1>::type
    >::value
   );

   // I need to find T which is the most restrictive common
   // type between T0 and T1
   typedef typename common<T0,T1>::type T

   T0 t0;
   T1 t1;

   T choose(bool c){
       return c ? t0 : t1;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that you need to roll your own. You can warp your types in a std::tuple, then pass it to `std::common_type`, e.g.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T1, class T2>
struct common {
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<0, typename std::common_type<std::tuple<T1>, std::tuple<T2>>::type>::type;
};

template <class T>
struct common<const T, T> {
    using type = const T;
};

template <class T>
struct common<T, const T> {
    using type = const T;
};

template <class T>
struct common<const T, const T> {
    using type = const T;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<common<int, int>::type, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<common<const int, int>::type, const int>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<common<int, int &>::type, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<common<int &, int &>::type, int &>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<common<int &, int const &>::type, int const &>::value, "");
    return 0;
}
```

But you have to create special cases for `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Taking inspiration from Oliv's solution, a possible C++11 version

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
using cond_t = decltype(false ? std::declval<T1>() : std::declval<T2>());

template <typename T1, typename T2>
using common = typename std::conditional<
   std::is_reference<T1>::value || std::is_reference<T2>::value,
   cond_t<T1, T2>,
   typename std::remove_reference<cond_t<T1 &, T2 &>>::type>::type;

int main()
 {
   using t1 = common<int,int>;
   using t2 = common<const int, int>;
   using t3 = common<int, int &>;
   using t4 = common<int &, int &>;
   using t5 = common<int &, int const &>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<t1, int>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t2, int const>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t3, int>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t4, int &>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t5, int const &>::value, "!" );  
 }
```

Comment: I would have selected this as the as the answer but it doesn't work for my version of visual studio. Still a good answer :) Upvoted

Answer (score 1):

In c++20 you could use `common_reference`, (there is an implementation in the range v3 library), but it needs some adaptation if none of the two types are reference:

```
template<class T,class U>
using common_t = conditional_t<is_reference_v<T> || is_reference_v<U>
                ,common_reference_t<T,U>
                ,remove_reference_t<common_reference_t<T&,U&>>>;
```

Comment: I need the solution for visual studio 2010 upwards but the answer is good info anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be hacked with decltype

https://godbolt.org/z/7xEv7Z

```
#include <type_traits>

// Use it to display the actual generated type
template <typename T> struct F;

template <typename T0,typename T1> 
struct Common
{
    typedef decltype(true ? ((T0)std::declval<T0>()) : ((T1)std::declval<T1>()) ) 
       type;
};

// Perform tests
F<Common<int,int>::type> f0;
F<Common<int &,int>::type> f1;
F<Common<const int &, int &>::type> f2;
F<Common<const int &, int>::type> f3;
```

Gives the results as expected

```
aggregate 'F<int> f0' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
aggregate 'F<int> f1' has incomplete type and
aggregate 'F<const int&> f2' has incomplete
aggregate 'F<int> f3' has incomplete type and
```

Comment: I believe this will not give you the desired result for the case `common<int, int>::type` as declval will always return a reference and the deduced type is, thus, going to be a reference…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: I thought I saw your answer here before. Why did you delete it?

Comment: @P.W my answer was simply to use `std::common_type` which is, unfortunately, not correct as `std::common_type` will decay the arguments and just return plain `int` in all the cases above…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel A small fix to using decltype will make it work. Just need to C style cast the result of decltype back to the type we want. I fixed the solution

Comment: Hmmm. It still is not perfect `Common<int const,int const>::type -> int`

Comment: @bradgonesurfing unfortunately, that will still not give the desired result for the case of `int, int const` I think…

Comment: Yes you are right. I noticed that too. I think felix has the right way but it requires specializations.

Comment: Though maybe it is good enough. Note that my use case is the ability to generate the function return type of `choose`  correctly so that it compiles. It doesn't really matter if the value types have const removed as there is an implicit copy occurring. so `const int ` can always be returned as `int` but `const int &` cannot be returned as `int &`

Comment: If the only goal here is to deduce the return type of `choose()`, then why not just use a trailing return type: `auto choose(bool c) -> decltype(c ? t0 : t1) {…}`?